# Release memory for array DML operations

Tags: delphi, firebird, c++builder, firebird2.5, firedac

I am using array DML operations to speed insert of large number of records into SQL database. The principle is described [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Array_DML_(FireDAC)). Sample code how this functionality is used:

```
TFDQuery *FDQuery1;
...
FDQuery1->SQL->Text = "insert into MyTab values (:p1, :p2, :p3)";
// here FDQuery1->Params collection is filled by 3 parameters
const int array_size = 100;
FDQuery1->Params->ArraySize = array_size;
FDQuery->Prepared = true;
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
  FDQuery1->Params[0]->AsIntegers[i] = i;
  FDQuery1->Params[1]->AsStrings[i] = "qwe";
  FDQuery1->Params[2]->Clear(i);
}
FDQuery1->Execute(array_size);
```

Essentially it means that instead of calling database engine client function for every row inserted, I first prepare data I need to insert as array. Typical size of array is 1000 items. Then I call client function with array as parameter. Unfortunately nowhere in documentation is described when is memory for array of parameters is released. Is it done when I unprepare query ?

```
TFDQuery *query;
...
query->Prepared = false;
```

Or is it done when I close the query ?

```
query->Close();
```

Or is it done when I set array size to 1 ?

```
query->Params->ArraySize = 1
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you write the array parameters?

Comment: It doesn't bear directly on your q, but which Sql Server type are you using?

Comment: I am using Firebird 2.5.4.

Comment: The memory for the param arrays is released when setting ArraySize to 1, but I am not sure if that is relevant here. Do you experience any problem or are you just curious?

Comment: Just dont want to leave allocated memory if it is no longer used. According to documentation (see link above) Oracle database will alocate 4000 bytes for every string. So for 1000 records its 4MB and we are talking only about one column. Some ot my tables have tens of columns. And my program uses more than one query. Its a matter of good programming style to release memory when it is no longer needed.

Comment: In that case setting ArraySize to 1 should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter collection should IMHO remain unchanged when unpreparing or closing the query by design because it's a manually populated collection (it is automatically prefilled by preprocessor when the command is assigned and [**ParamCreate**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.ParamCreate) enabled; corrected at command preparation). But you may want to execute the same command later without setting up the same collection.

If you know that you won't execute the same command again, you can call the [**Clear**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollection.Clear) method:

```cpp
query->Params->Clear();
```

If you want to preserve parameter settings, and release only resources consumed by the value storage, you can reduce number of parameter *rows* through the [**ArraySize**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParams.ArraySize) property:

```cpp
query->Params->ArraySize = 1
```